# Cannot edit CodeMirror or Ace in a taskpane of an add-in in Excel for Windows

Tags: focus, ms-office, office-js, codemirror, ace-editor

I just realized that we cannot modify texts in CodeMirror or Ace in a taskpane of an add-in in Excel for Windows.

I have made a test html page with [this code](https://jsbin.com/bivezolayo/5/edit?html,output), and link it to a manifest file of an Excel add-in. It works well in Excel Online (in Chrome and IE), Excel for Mac. However, in Excel for Windows, 1) `textarea` works well; 2) We could put the focus on CodeMirror, whereas we can NOT type anything; 3) When we put the focus on Excel then back on Ace, we can NOT type anything.

I have not tested other JavaScript-based source editor, because my webpage is actually built with angularjs and I need `ui-codemirror` or `ui-ace`. I have tested them, they have the same bug, though i will not list the testing code here because I don't think it is the `ui-` that causes the problem.

Is anyone aware of this odd behavior? How could we fix this? Is there any workaround or alternative?

**PS:** I have found a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45184664/702977) from the author of the CodeMirror, but I don't know if (and how) it can help fix add-ins in Excel for Windows.

**PS2:** I just realised that, if we click on Excel, then click on a useless area (somewhere without element) in the taskpane before clicking in the Ace textarea, we could then edit its content. Does anyone know how to use this to make a workaround for the Ace textarea? This method does not work with CodeMirror textarea...

Answer (score 0):

I think yo can follow this steps mentioned here.
I hope it will solve your issue as it solve the issue for that user:

https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/3375

Comment: That user is myself... But the problem was not fully solved, as I mentioned in the end, I tried to make a [directive](https://jsbin.com/davimigaya/2/edit?html,output), it did not work in Excel for Windows.