# Use Monaco Editor in AngularJS 1.X

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, monaco-editor, ui-codemirror

Because of [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45531106/cannot-edit-codemirror-or-ace-in-a-taskpane-of-an-add-in-in-excel-for-windows), I am trying to use another JavaScript-based source editor than CodeMirror and Ace, which can work with `AngularJS 1.X`. I am then investigating [Monaco Editor](https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor).

I can well run [this sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor-samples/blob/master/sample-editor/index.html). But I don't know how to make it work with AngularJS 1.X.

For example, I want to bind `ng-if`, `ng-model` and `ng-change` to the editor, to decide when and what to display, and run a function if there is any change. With [ui-codemirror](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-codemirror), we could write with a directive:

```
<textarea ng-if="condition" ng-change="change(content)" ng-model="content" ui-codemirror="{ mode: 'application/json' }"></textarea>
```

So does anyone know if there is such `ui-` directive for Monaco Editor? Is there any workaround to achieve the same thing within angular framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started to write a [ui-monacoeditor](https://github.com/chengtie/ui-monacoeditor) by imitating ui-codemirror. It is not complete yet, but works for my limited use.

Comment: it still works... if there is anything that does not work for you, just investigate the code, it is not hard to amend it for your case...

Comment: My hero!! Thanks dude